# How to use `subset` in a function?

Tags: r, function, subset

I created a function that relies on subsetting. `subset` works when it's outside of the function but not within the function. I cannot figure out what's wrong.

The expression does not work when in a function.

```
library(dplyr)
my_function <- function(a, b, c) {
    tmp_output <- subset(my_df, vector1 == a & vector2 == b & vector3 == c, 
                         select=column1) %>% 
                           sum
}

my_function("spec1", "temp2", 300)
tmp_output
# Error: object 'tmp_output' not found
```

The expression works when it's not part of a function.

```
tmp_output <- subset(my_df, vector1 == "spec1" & vector2 == "temp2" & vector3 == 300, 
                     select=column1) %>% 
                       sum
tmp_output
#[1] 0
```

Not sure what is going wrong in the transition there.

I am expecting to get a sum of the rows that have been subset in the output of `tmp_output`. It is obviously not creating a value at all unless it's written outside of the function, as shown. I suspect that there is something about `subset` that doesn't work well in a function but I cannot figure out the workaround.

### Data

```
my_df <- data.frame(
  vector1=c(rep("spec1", 6), rep("spec2", 6)), 
  vector2=c(rep("temp1", 6), rep("temp2", 6)), 
  vector3=c(rep(300, 6), rep(500, 6)), 
  column1=c(rep(2, 4), rep(5, 4), rep(11, 4))
)
```

Comment: It works except you are assigning the result and not returning it.  Either don't assign it so it's returned by default or return it explicitly.

Comment: your variable `tmp_output` only exists inside your function (lookup scoped variables) which is why you are getting your error. If you want to assign the results of your function to tmp_output you can run `tmp_output <- my_function("spec1", "temp2", 300)`

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment, there are two issues.

Your function doesn't yet return anything. Add a line `return(tmp_output)` or just remove the assignment `tmp_output <-`, I'll show you the latter. You can also use the base R pipe, `|>`, to avoid loading `dplyr` extra for the pipe.

The result of `subset` will be a column, so what you want is `colSums` instead of `sum`.

```
my_function <- function(a, b, c) {
  subset(my_df, vector1 == a & vector2 == b & vector3 == c, 
         select=column1) |> colSums()
}
```

Now it should work:

```
my_function("spec1", "temp2", 300)
# column1 
#       0 

my_function("spec1", "temp1", 300)
# column1 
#      18
```

---

*Data:*

```
my_data <- structure(list(vector1 = c("spec1", "spec1", "spec1", "spec1", 
"spec1", "spec1", "spec2", "spec2", "spec2", "spec2", "spec2", 
"spec2"), vector2 = c("temp1", "temp1", "temp1", "temp1", "temp1", 
"temp1", "temp2", "temp2", "temp2", "temp2", "temp2", "temp2"
), vector3 = c(300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 300, 500, 500, 500, 500, 
500, 500), column1 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5, 5, 11, 11, 11, 11
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```